DataGridView doubleClick event
Using VB.Net 2010, I have a DGV to display various fields from Access 2010 table, 7 cells across.
I also have have 7 text boxes. I need to double-click on the ROW HEADER, of any row, to display the data in the text boxes.
I'm nit sure what to try, or how to do this
